# Doctrine NOT IN query

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

I have:

```
$from = new \DateTime($from);
            $to = new \DateTime($to);
            $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
            $reservations = $qb
                    ->select('rr.id')
                    ->from('\Model\Reservation', 're')
                    ->join('re.rooms', 'rr')
                    ->where('(re.fromDate < ?1 AND re.toDate <= ?2 AND re.toDate > ?1) OR (re.fromDate >= ?1 AND re.fromDate < ?2)')
                    ->setParameters(array(1 => $from, 2 => $to))
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

And I have result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } }
```

I want to write query with Doctrine like SELECT ... WHERE NOT IN first query, but the query:

```
    $rooms = $qb->select('ro')
            ->from('\Model\Room', 'ro')                   
            ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('ro.id', $reservations))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

give me error:

> ERROR: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Help me, please.

Comment: Whats `$reservations` looks like ?

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(2) } }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
->where($qb->expr()->notIn('ro.id', $reservations))
```

to

```
->where($qb->expr()->notIn('ro.id', array_column($reservations, 'id')))
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed the problem. I needed a new QueryBuilder for second query.